# How do I easily set devise in ruby on rails 3 to email forgotten password information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is there a quick way to do this? I've never used mail in rails before.
Isn't this all set up in devise leaving me a small modification to make to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your user model, you need a `devise` call to tell devise what facets of it you want to use. As long as it includes `:recoverable`, devise itself includes all the views and logic to make this work (except actually sending the mail - you need to configure your mail server yourself).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :recoverable
end
```